# Elasticsearch autocomplete rest of word

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I've got a working version of autocomplete for elastic search. One issue though, is if I search for xbox 360. I get xbox 360 and xbox one coming back as possible suggestions.

I'd like for suggestions to only consider suggestions which contain the whole query up until that point of suggestion. For example if I type xbox 3, elastic search should never return xbox one, but only xbox 360.

My query is running against the _suggestions end point.
My config is as follows.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "query" : {
        "properties" : {
             "product" : { "type" : "string" },
             "name_suggest" : {
                 "type" :     "completion"
              }
         }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show us your request to the suggester? Certain options that are/aren't set in the suggester could be causing this issue, or you might be missing something that will solve it. If you provide some more detail for us we might be able to spot it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any index or search analyzers on _all? Is that all of your mapping? Can you show your documents? And +1 for showing the request

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing the completion suggester. If that is the case, you can use this as an example:

```
PUT /mymusicsuggest
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "album": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "index_analyzer": "simple",
          "search_analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /mymusicsuggest/album/1
{
    "name" : "Tori Amos - Little Earthquakes",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "earthquakes", "little", "tori", "amos" ],
        "output": "Tori Amos - Little Earthquakes",
        "payload" : { "songs" : ["11861","11839","11849","11853","11841", "11847","11851","11845","11855","11843","11859","11857"] },
        "weight" : 10
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html